# How to check undefined variable in sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass, node-sass

iam trying to set color var in local (site specific) and a global(generic) sass file to add colors to websites in AEM. I have followed following approaches to check undefined. But none of them seems to be working. getting undefined variable $light-gray... Iam using gulp sass 4.0.1

```css
@if variable-exists($light-gray) {
  color: $light-gray;
 }else{
  color: lightgray;
 }
  
  /*------------------------------------------*/
  
  if($light-gray, $light-gray, lightgray)
```

What would be the other approach

Comment: How and where do you define the variable? Is is defined in a file that is included before this one, because it won't be defined at the point this file is hit otherwise.

Comment: yes... colorvar is defined local and been called before the generic. So initially all variables will be loaded followed by generic file will read all variables. But as per my condition, it has nothing to do with how we are importing rt?. coz I have checked the condition whether its defined.

Comment: - In colorvar.scss., I have defined color variables
- In colors.scss., I have called colorsvar.scss., and written condition.

colorsvar.scss is site specfic (i.e. I have 3-4 websites in a package)(I have different colorsvar.scss files ( - depends on colors required for each website)).

- But a generic path with filename (colors.scss) reads (colorsvar.scss) depends on site we are loading. Here when Iam loading site2., the color variables defined for site1 is showing undefined.

Comment: Sounds like you have a very complicated setup, not good when debugging ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured the issue. Its giving undefined coz i was defining `@if variable-exists($my-variable) not @if variable-exists(my-variable)` .. Since only string is being considered as param in @if condition., and using @, It is converting the entire variable including @ and getting var undefined.

Hence answer is `@if variable-exists(my-variable)`

Another interesting I have found is, the variable we are defining should not be any standard color code value. If defined any standard colorcode, SASS automatically throws an error 'param should be a string'... 'standard color code cannot be considered as srting'...

e.g. `@gray: #ccc` ., on passing `gray` as a variable name, SASS throws an error saying 'it is expecting string'.

Thought this additional input might help few people.